# Como passar um vetor da classe vector como parâmetro de uma função?

Tags: c++, vector

O conteúdo do meu vector são os dados que desejo colocar na matriz:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> dados;
    int valores[4];
    string val;
    ifstream arq ("matriz.txt");
    if(arq.is_open())
    {
        while(! arq.eof())
        {
            getline(arq, val);
            int num;
            stringstream ss(val);
            while(ss >> num)
            {
                dados.push_back(num);
            }
        }
    // mais codigos aqui
    }
    }
```

Em C++:

```
void Matrix::IniMatrix(int *vetor)
{
    for(int i=0; i<getLinha(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<getColuna(); j++)
        {
            elem[i][j] = vetor[1]; // int **elem (este é o tipo que esta declarado elem)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como é que o primeiro código se relaciona com o segundo ? está a tentar passar um vetor nativo, `int []` ou um vetor da classe `vector`, um  `vector<int>` ?

Answer (score 0):

É uma pergunta já antiga e a resposta parece bem simples, a não ser que eu esteja deixando escapar alguma coisa...

```
// void Matrix::IniMatrix(int *vetor)
void Matrix::IniMatrix(vector<int>& vetor)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < getLinha(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < getColuna(); j++)
      if (i < vetor.size()) // verifica se o indice e' valido no vetor
        elem[i][j] = vetor[i]; // int **elem (este é o tipo que esta declarado elem)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A sintaxe de um vetor como parâmetro em C é:

```
método(tipo_do_vetor nomedovetor[]){
//comandos aqui
}
```

Exemplo:

```
int somadedois(int x[]){
    return (x[0]+x[1]);
}
```

No seu caso, o método ficaria assim:

```
void Matrix::IniMatrix(int vetor[])
{
   for(int i=0; i<getLinha(); i++)
   {
       for(int j=0; j<getColuna(); j++)
       {
           elem[i][j] = vetor[1]; // int **elem (este é o tipo que esta declarado elem)
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: esta resposta não acrescenta nada, já que "int somadedois(int x[])" é a mesma coisa que   "int somadedois(int*  x)" como já está sendo usada na pergunta